# Tail recursion, should I use it in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, tail-recursion

I know that tail recursion in Haskell is subject to some difficulties due to its being lazy. That is, is it sensible to use tail recursion in Haskell?

Comment: "I know that tail recursion in Haskell is subject to some difficulties due to its being lazy." It is?  Could you provide a reference for such a claim?

Comment: @TomEllis: The problem is that lazyness can cause things like foldl and similar hand-built recursive loops to leak space.

Answer (score 7):

The answer, as usual with these big questions, is "it depends".

When you're programming in a lazy style, you can often get away with naive recursion, for example

```
 map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
 map _ []     = []
```

Is actually how `map` is defined in the standard libs. And this is good, since a tail recursive function yields the result generally can't be nicely lazy, a tail recursive map won't terminate if you did something like `head . map (+1) $ [1..]`.

However, sometimes we don't want to be lazy. The classic example is when we're too lazy and start to build up thunks that we really just want evaluated, like when summing a list.

```
sum xs = someFold (+) 0 xs
```

Now since `+` is strict in it's arguments and associative, there's no reason to use `foldr` but `foldl'` is perfect, it's tail recursive and evaluates strictly which gives noticeable space improvements. The `'` is important, in many tail recursive functions, there's an accumulator that's modified on each recursive step, `foldl'` will force it's evaulation which prevents our tail recursive function from being too lazy and building up thunks.

So the moral of the story, when you're programming lazily and producing lazy datastructures, tail recursion isn't as big a deal. But when you're programming strictly and using functions strict in both arguments, then tail recursion is very important for maintaining good performance.

Comment: I wonder, isn't `head . map (+1) $ [1..]` the same as `head (map (+1) $ [1..] x)`? If yes, why do you use 1) $ 2) funct composition? 3) [1..] ? Shouldn't it be just `head $ map (+1) [1..]`?

Comment: `f . g $ x` is the same as `f $ g $ x` is the same as `f (g x)`. Some people prefer the first form because it emphasizes building a functional pipeline then applying the argument at the end with `$`.

Comment: @Alex I tend to write functions as `compose . as . many . as . possible $ apply` it's a style choice

Comment: Composition is associative. It makes certain refactorings easier as you can cut a part anywhere in the middle of a long pipeline and name it.

Answer (score 7):

Tail recursion isn't as straightforward or as big of a deal in Haskell as it is in strict languages. Usually, instead, you should aim to write *productive* functions. For instance, `foldr` is often productive

```
foldr f z []     = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = x `f` foldr f z xs
```

If the combining function `f` is able to produce a partial result lazily then whatever is consuming the results from `foldr` can demand them lazily as well. A typical example is "foldr identity"

```
foldr (:) [] [1,2,3]          -- "force" it once
1 : {{ foldr (:) [] [2,3] }}
```

where the `{{...}}` is a lazy thunk. If the calling context of this `foldr` is, say, `head` then we're done

```
head (foldr (:) [] [1,2,3])
head (1 : {{ foldr (:) [] [2,3] }})
1
```

However, if the `f` in `foldr` is strict then `foldr` can create linearly many calling frames

```
foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3]
1 + {{ foldr (+) 0 [2,3] }}           -- we know it's one more than *something*
1 + (2 + {{ foldr (+) 0 [3] }})       -- ...
1 + (2 + (3 + {{ foldr (+) 0 [] }}))
1 + (2 + (3 + 0))                     -- and now we can begin to compute
1 + (2 + 3)
1 + 5
6
```

While `foldl'` lets the strict combining function operate immediately

```
foldl' f z []     = z
foldl' f z (x:xs) = let z' = f z x in z' `seq` foldl' f z' xs
```

where that `seq` noise forces Haskell to evaluate like this

```
foldl' (+) 0 [1,2,3]
foldl' (+) (1+0) [2,3]
foldl' (+) 1 [2,3]
foldl' (+) (1+2) [3]
foldl' (+) 3 [3]
foldl' (+) (3+3) []
foldl' (+) 6 []
6
```

Which looks a lot like a tail recursive call.

See [the wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tail_recursion) for a bit more detail.

Comment: How do you decide whether to make a function tail recursive or just productive?

Comment: Generally if something has streaming behavior or takes advantage of laziness then productivity is better. When something is strict and needs to run in constant space then tail recursion is better.